# Pandas multi-index conditional filtering

Tags: python, pandas

The code below calculates column correlation into a Pandas series multi-index:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
df.corr().unstack()
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| ('sepal length (cm)', 'sepal length (cm)') | 1 |
| ('sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)') | -0.11757 |
| ('sepal length (cm)', 'petal length (cm)') | 0.871754 |
| ('sepal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)') | 0.817941 |

I'd like to filter out correlation rows between feature and itself (e.g. first row). This is a general question for me - how to filter multi-index using conditions between the index levels.

Answer (score -1):

Edited 10/8/2021
Assuming the is only ever two levels in the index you can use the following method. If there are more than two levels you can add a loop.

```
#get index of df
idx = df.index

#build a mask when the two levels of the index are the same
mask = idx.get_level_values(0)!=idx.get_level_values(1)

#apply mask
result = df.iloc[mask]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, the features are the original features from the "Iris" data set; correlation is calculated via correlation matrix, and finally the result is un-stacked in a manner that results with a correlation Pandas series. the series has a multi-index: for each correlation value the two features as two levels of indexes. I would like to filter out rows in which the first index value equals the second index value, e.g.: ('sepal length (cm)', 'sepal length (cm)')

Comment: Ah now I understand. See modified answer.

Comment: This solves the problem - thanks! (I actually used the inverse mask to take out the same index value records)

Comment: Ah yes it should have `!=`. I have now changed.